# Python NameError 'Y' not found

Tags: python

I was trying to make a program that generate a number within range of 1-6 randomly. And will stop when the user input 'N'

Here is my code

```
import random
def roll():
    min = 1
    max = 6
    value = random.randrange(min,max+1)
    print(value)

x = 'Y'
while (x == 'Y'):
    roll()
    x = chr(input("again?(Y/N)"))
```

and this is the error message

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "Dice.py", line 11, in
>   
>       x = chr(input("again?(Y/N)"))   File "", line 1, in  NameError: name 'Y' is not defined

Comment: You should use `raw_input` instead of `input`

Comment: In Python 3 (which I assume is Steven using) was raw_input() was renamed to input() - so now input() returns the exact string.

Comment: What version of python are you using? Python2.x input differs from Python3.x, try raw_input

Comment: @dram, If OP is using Python 3.x, then he would get `TypeError: an integer is required` as `chr()` required integer input

Comment: Your assumption is wrong, he is using python 2 but tries to use python 3 function `input` which has slighlty different meaning in python 2.

Comment: it should be python 3.6 but raw_input works fine

Comment: I was working with geany, and it just found out that it uses python 2, problem solved everybody, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use raw_input in Python 2 to get a string, input in Python 2 is equivalent to eval(raw_input).
So, When you enter something like Y in input it thinks that you're looking for a variable named Y:

```
import random
def roll():
    min = 1
    max = 6
    value = random.randrange(min,max+1)
    print(value)

x = 'Y'
while (x == 'Y'):
    roll()
    x = (raw_input("again?(Y/N)"))
```

USE `raw_input()` and remove `chr()` function

Answer (score 0):

change your code to use `str` instead of `chr`

**chr() : Return a string of one character whose ASCII code is the integer i. For example, chr(97) returns the string 'a'. The argument must be in the range [0..255]**

```
import random
def roll():
    min = 1
    max = 6
    value = random.randrange(min,max+1)
    print(value)

x = 'Y'
while (x == 'Y'):
    roll()
    x = input("again?(Y/N)")    #Python 3
    x = raw_input("again?(Y/N)")  #Python 2
```

Comment: `input()` in python3.x returns a string so the conversion `str(input())` is unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

this works thank you

```
import random
def roll():
    min = 1
    max = 6
    value = random.randrange(min,max+1)
    print(value)

x = 'Y'
while (x == 'Y'):
    roll()
    x = raw_input("again?(Y/N)")
```

Answer (score 0):

without typecasting in `python 3.x`

`x = input("again?(Y/N)")`